# unable to create TLB from the Com dll

Tags: interop

I have WMI class in a COM dll. I was trying to create a RCW for it in C#.NET. I used tlbexp.exe to get the type library from the COM dll but it throws an error stating "unable to load one of the dependencies".

I understood that it is trying to load one of the DLL it is referring internally, how can i come to know which dll it is trying to load and can i successfully complete the process if i some how get the dll from internet?

Answer (score 1):

Use "[Dependency Walker](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dependencywalker.com%2F&ei=49xmSpjrCJ3cmgP8gMn4Dw&usg=AFQjCNH2xHd_jlOFVUuUCGsxzdiAM2BlXg&sig2=8pPQcbnsArV_XG5tekAYOg)" on your DLL.

Comment: I have used that, it says DWMAPI.DLL is missing. it is a DLL which is not loaded unless it is really needed. how can i overcome this loading?

Comment: This says the DLL is delay loaded. Most often this means that the application won't use the functionality from the DLL unless it is present. However it depends on correct implementation on the application's part.